# Mobile web server with ASP

Tags: mobile, asp-classic, embeddedwebserver

Does anyone know of any embeddable Software/libraries for android/ios/etc that will provide web server capabilities for rendering ASP pages?

I'm looking for a solution where you can build an app with the library, point it to an asp page and have it run like it would on IIS.

to be clear, I'm just looking at asp, not necessarily asp.net (although if it did both, great).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows CE](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/develop/windows-embedded-compact-7-for-developers.aspx) provides an [embedded web server that supports classic ASP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834461.aspx).

Quote from MSDN:

> Windows CE supports a subset of the ASP-page functionality that IIS
>   supports.